# Почему контентная часть все еще налазит на footer?

Tags: css, layout

Почему контентная часть все еще налазит на footer ?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

 body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.42;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 940px + 20px;
}



ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

  .clearfix {
    content: '';
    clear: both; 
    display: block;
 }   

                                            /* ------------- HEADER ------------- */

.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px -0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    height: 60px;  
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

                                     /* ------------- HEADER - left ------------- */

                             
.header__left {
    width: 50%;
}

.user {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
 }

.user__avatar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.user__avatar-pic {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #cccccc;

}

.user__name {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 200px;
}

                                         /* ------------- HEADER - right ------------- */

.header__right {
    width: 45%;
}

 .contacts {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.contacts__link {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px ;
    color: #33c1e3;
    font-weight: bold;  
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;

}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 35px;
    color: white;
    right: -35px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid silver;

    }

.dropdown:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    top: -50px;
/*     border: 1px solid red; */
}

.dropdown__item {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 150px;
}

.contacts span {
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #33c1e3;

}

.dropdown__item-link {
    color: #33c1e3;
}

.contacts:hover .dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
} 

.dropdown .fas, .fab {
    color: #33c1e3;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
} 

/* .triangle {
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    position: absolute;
}

.triangle:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    top: -31px;
} */


                                         /* ------------- sidebar ------------- */


.main-left   {
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    text-align: right;
}

.main-right  {
    float: right;
    width: 720px;
        border: 2px solid green;

}

.about__left  {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

.about__right  {
    float: right;
    width: 470px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    position: relative;
}



.about__pic_link {
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    object-fit: cover;
    transition: .7s;
}

.about__pic_link:hover {
        border: 2px solid #2962ff;
        transition: .7s;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 300px;

}

.nav__link {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    transition: .3s;
}

.nav__link:hover {
        border-right: 4px solid #33c1e3;
        color: #33c1e3;
}

.nav__list .fas {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

                                      /* ------------- main right ------------- */

.about__right {
}

.about-title {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.about__desc {
  
}



.fa-download {
    margin-right: 6px;
    color: #ff3632;
    transition: 0.4s;

}

.about-btn:hover {
    background-color: #ff3632;
    border-radius: 22px;
    padding: 6px 22px;
    border: 2px solid #ff3632;
    color: white;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.about-btn:hover .fa-download {
    margin-right: 6px;
    color: white;
    transition: 0.4s;
}


.about__right {
    // background-color: red;
    width: 490px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: right;
    align-items: flex-end;

}

.job-item {
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    width: 350px;
    text-align: left;
    color: grey;
    box-shadow: -1px 2px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    transition: 0.6s;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;

}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}


.career__list {
    // display: flex;
    // align-items: center;
    // justify-content: center;
}

.career__item {
    text-align: right;
    
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.career__item:first-child .career__block:before {
    display: none;
}

.career__item:last-child .career__block:after {
    display: none;
}


.career__block {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align-last: left;
    
}

                                               //line
.career__block:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 1px;
    background: grey;
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    
    top: -20px; // 22 - для універсальної обводки крапки. А так так можна значення 0 
    bottom: 50%;
                                                //dot's border
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.career__block:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 1px;
    background: grey;
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    
    top: 50%;
    bottom: -22px; // 22 - для універсальної обводки крапки. А так так можна значення 0 
                                              //dot's border
    margin-top: 10px;
}


                                               // year 
.career__year {
    position: absolute;
    left: -75px;
    top: 50%;
    
    right: 100%;
    margin-right: 39px;
    
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    
}

                                               // dot
.career__year:after {
    content: "";
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #33c1e3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    
    right: -15px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    z-index: 2;
}






                                                /* ------------- footer ------------- */

.wrapper:after {
    content: " ";
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #414141;
    box-shadow: 2px 1px 7px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    margin-top: -50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.footer-left {
    float: left;
}

.footer-right {
    float: right;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}

.copyright  {
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.copyright-text {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: grey;
}

.socials-item {
   display: inline-block;
}

.socials-item_link {

}

.footer-right .fab {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 8px;
    color: #414141;
    background-color: grey;
    transition: 0.3s;  
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.footer-right .fab:hover {
    background-color: #448aaf;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="maincontent">   
                                                                                 <!---------- HEADER ---------->
            <header class="header"> 
                <div class="container">   
                    <div class="header__left">  
                        <div class="user">
                            <div class="user__avatar">
                                <img class="user__avatar-pic" src="https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Screenshot_1_198.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="user__name">Yaroslav Prokhorenko</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="header__right">
                        <div class="contacts">
                            <button class="contacts__link" href="#"><span>my contacts </span></button>
                            <ul class="dropdown">
                                <div class="triangle"></div>
                                <li class="dropdown__item">                                 
                                    <p class="dropdown__item-link"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>sample@email</p>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown__item">                                 
                                    <p class="dropdown__item-link"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>+380 546 5345</p>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown__item">
                                    <p class="dropdown__item-link"><i class="fab fa-skype"></i>sample</p>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>   
            </header> 
                
            <div class="content">
                <div class="container ">
                                                                          <!---------- main left ---------->
                    <div class="main-left">
                        <nav class="nav">
                            <ul class="nav__list">
                              <li class="nav__item nav__item_active"><a href="#" class="nav__link"><i class="fas fa-user-secret"></i>About Me</a></li>
                              <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link"><i class="fas fa-rocket"></i>Career</a></li>
                              <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link"><i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>Portfolio</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                                                                          <!---------- main right --------->
                    <div class="main-right">
                                <div class="about">
                                    <div class="about-title">
                                        Career
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="about__left">
                                        <div class="about__pic">
                                            <img class="about__pic_link" src="https://www.linkpicture.com/q/ed-ward-zcABf34bdpY-unsplash.jpg" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="about__right">
                                         <ul class="career__list">
                                                <li class="career__item">
                                                    <div class="career__block">
                                                        <div class="career__title">
                                                            Kyiv National University 
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="career__occ">
                                                            Group Leader Assistant
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="career__date">
                                                            2010-2015
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="career__year">
                                                            2015
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="career__item">
                                                    <div class="career__block">
                                                        <div class="career__title">
                                                            Kyiv National University 
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="career__occ">
                                                            Group Leader Assistant
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="career__date">
                                                            2010-2015
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="career__year">
                                                            2015
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                 <li class="career__item">
                                                    <div class="career__block">
                                                        <div class="career__title">
                                                            Kyiv National University 
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="career__occ">
                                                            Group Leader Assistant
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="career__date">
                                                            2010-2015
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="career__year">
                                                            2015
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>  
                                                 
                                                 <li class="career__item">
                                                    <div class="career__block">
                                                        <div class="career__title">Kyiv National University</div>
                                                        <div class="career__occ">Group Leader Assistant</div>
                                                        <div class="career__date">2010-2015</div>
                                                        <div class="career__year">2015</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="career__item">
                                                    <div class="career__block">
                                                        <div class="career__title">
                                                            Kyiv National University
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="career__occ">
                                                            Group Leader Assistant
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="career__date">
                                                            2010-2015
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="career__year">
                                                            2015
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="career__item">
                                                    <div class="career__block">
                                                        <div class="career__title">
                                                            Kyiv National University
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="career__occ">
                                                            Group Leader Assistant
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="career__date">
                                                            2010-2015
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="career__year">
                                                            2015
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                               <li class="career__item">
                                                    <div class="career__block">
                                                        <div class="career__title">
                                                            Kyiv National University
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="career__occ">
                                                            Group Leader Assistant
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="career__date">
                                                            2010-2015
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="career__year">
                                                            2015
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="career__item">
                                                    <div class="career__block">
                                                        <div class="career__title">
                                                            Kyiv National University
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="career__occ">
                                                            Group Leader Assistant
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="career__date">
                                                            2010-2015
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="career__year">
                                                            2015
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                          </ul>                 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>     
            </div>   
       </div> 
 </div>           
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <div class="footer-left">
                <div class="copyright">
                   <p class="copyright-text"> © Design was created in SampleSchool </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-right">
                <ul class="socials">
                   <li class="socials-item"><a class="socials-item_link" href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                   <li class="socials-item"><a class="socials-item_link" href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                   <li class="socials-item"><a class="socials-item_link" href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Из за свойства `overflow: hidden;` у `.wrapper`

Comment: Может просто убрать `margin-top: -50px;` у `.footer`?

Comment: Если убрать margin-top: -50px; то при минимуме контента на странице footer буде не виден (wrapper min-height: 100%; )

Comment: Ну тогда просто добавьте `overflow: hidden` в `.container`

Comment: @laukhin-andrey работает, спасибо!